# Find $\sum_{i=[1,\ldots,n], j=[1,\ldots,m]: i\neq j }\frac{1}{j}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I have the following double   $\sum_{i=[1,\ldots,n], j=[1,\ldots,m]: i\neq j }\frac{1}{j}$.

If I ignore restriction $i \neq j$ then 
$$
\sum_{i=[1,\ldots,n], j=[1,\ldots,m] }\frac{1}{j}=n \sum_{ j=[1,\ldots,m] }\frac{1}{j} \le n(1+\ln(m))
$$

Now, I am not sure how to it with this restiction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the restriction you have

$$\begin{align*}\sum_{j=1}^m\;\sum_{i\in[1..n],i\ne j}\frac1j&=\begin{cases}
\sum_{j=1}^m\frac{n-1}j,&\text{if }n\ge m\\\\
\sum_{j=1}^m\frac{n-1}j+\sum_{j=n+1}^m\frac1j,&\text{if }n<m
\end{cases}\\\\
&=\begin{cases}
(n-1)H_m,&\text{if }n\ge m\\\\
(n-1)H_m+(H_m-H_n),&\text{if }n<m
\end{cases}\\\\
&=\begin{cases}
(n-1)H_m,&\text{if }n\ge m\\\\
nH_m-H_n,&\text{if }n<m\;,
\end{cases}
\end{align*}$$

where $H_n$ is the $n$-the harmonic number.