# What is $\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=i+1}^n \frac{1}{j}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

What is $$\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=i+1}^n \frac{1}{j}$$?

**What I did**
I know that 
\begin{align*}
&\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=i+1}^n \frac{1}{j}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=i+1}^n \frac{1}{j}+\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^i \frac{1}{j}-\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^i \frac{1}{j}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{j}-\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^i \frac{1}{j}\\
&=m H_n-\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^i \frac{1}{j}\\
\end{align*}
but how to compute $\sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^i \frac{1}{j}$?

I have some what related question here [Find $\sum_{i=[1,\ldots,n], j=[1,\ldots,m]: i\neq j }\frac{1}{j}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1016007/find-sum-i-1-ldots-n-j-1-ldots-m-i-neq-j-frac1j)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $$
\sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^i \frac 1j = 
\sum_{j=1}^m \sum_{i=j}^n \frac 1j = 
\sum_{j=1}^m (m-j+1) \frac 1j = (m+1)H_m - m 
$$

Comment: By the way you mean $m$ not $n$ in your answer, right?

Comment: I will accepted. The sysmtem tells me I have to wait 5 min.

Comment: Do you think I Should I assume that $n \ge m$ in my result?

Comment: @Boby why is that?

Comment: Actually, never mind. The result holds for any $n$ and $m$. Thank you for your help.